# chrome.notifications.clear - Android?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, android-notifications

(Revised) Recently I started using Kiwi Browser for Android because I wanted to use a Chrome Extension that I had made. My issue is with chrome.notifications.clear not being able to remove the notification from the Notification Area. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Note that I'm willing to use something other than chrome.notifications if that's what it takes. The only requirement is that the extension posts the notification to the Notification Area and is also able to remove it.

Comment: chrome.notifications.clear is not related to Android, it's an API for chrome extensions which were never compatible with Android even though some mobile browsers can run extensions.

Comment: just a note for future comments, w0xx0m's reply was to the original text of my question which has been vastly modified.

Comment: My comment is still relevant: extensions don't have any special handling for Android so the only thing you can do is to report it to the Kiwi browser maker and hope they'll implement the necessary support.